# ADODB recordset error "Operation is not allowed when the object is open" (3705)

Tags: asp-classic, adodb, recordset

I have a legacy ASP application that I support. By support I mean that I haven't touched it since about 2005 because its just worked.

However there were a couple of data issues in the Access database that the ASP application uses. So like a fool I opened the database directly over a fileshare (using MS Access 2007), fixed the data and saved it down (in Access 2000 format).

Now the application will retrieve and display the data OK, but any updates fail with the error `3705: Operation is not allowed when the object is open`. I have not changed the code in any way, the only change was the data update and database save.

I've found plenty of examples of this error, but they all relate to fairly simple issues like ensuring the recordset is closed before opening it, changing the CursorLocation enum, etc. I've tried most of these in the vain hope that something will work, but nothing has.

Any ideas how can I fix this?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I've installed a web based access database management system, and have tried to compact and repair the database. I received the error:

```
The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot open the file '<snip>'. It is
already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view
its data. (-2147217911)
```

I have run the macro detailed [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/285822) to determine who is logged onto the database, and just showed the admin user (which was me - while running it)

Comment: "Saved it down" Did you save or save as? Have you got an *.ldb hanging around? Have you tried a compact and repair?

Comment: I saved (not save as). There is no ldb file. I tried a compact and repair after I discovered the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Another thought, when you uploaded, did the permissions get changed? This could explain why you can read but not write. MS Access needs read/write for both the file and the folder.

Comment: Thanks - that's something I'm trying to find out (as I only have access to the fileshare). However as I only did a save (ie, I didn't explicitly copy over it or anything) I wouldn't have thought so. The only thing I'm unsure about is saving over a fileshare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Remou's comment above about checking the file and folder permissions was correct.

I had our server admin check the permissions, and it seems that the write access had dropped off the folder (and the files also inherit their permissions from the folder). He said that this has happened before when saving directly over the fileshare.

(accepting in lieu of an answer from @Remou)

Answer (score 0):

Those errors mean one thing: the database file is opened by some other process and thus is being locked.

Most likely that "web based access database management system" is the culprit, try to find how you can configure it to not lock the file, or get rid of it.

As a work around or way to verify the real problem, you can copy the .mdb file into different location and change the classic ASP connection string to check if you can update the database in its new location.

Comment: Thanks, these are all valid points, but in this case @Remou's comment helped me fix the issue - it was a file / folder permissions issue.